# what is best way to handle history tables in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, database-design, database-diagrams

I am working on the following database structure/diagram for an app using postgresql 13 server

**Is there a better way to design these table relationships with the tables `subscriptions_history` and `rentals_history` to track history of another tables `subscriptions` and `rentals`?**

Below are descriptions of the tables.

> table `movies`

- id(primary key)
- name
- category
- subscription_price
- rental_price
- rental_period

> table `subscriptions`

this table is used to track a single rental of a specific `movies.id`. One entry for each movie. So the row gets updated whenever the movie is rented again, thus why we have `last_updated`. We then track history of rental with the next table right below [table `subscriptions_history`]

- id(primary key)
- price_paid
- date_subscribed
- subscription_status
- last_updated
- movie_id => foreignkey(movies.id)

> table `subscriptions_history`

this table is used to track the number of times or subscription history of a specific `subscriptions.id` is renewed

- id(primary key)
- price_paid
- date_subscribed
- subscription_status
- subscription_id => foreignkey(subscriptions.id)

> table `rentals`

this table is used to track a single rental of a specific `movies.id`. One entry for each movie rental. So the row gets updated whenever the movie is returned or renewed, thus why we have `last_updated`. We then track history of rental with the next table right below [table `rental_history`]

- id(primary key)
- price_paid
- rental_date
- return_date
- renew_date
- rental_status
- last_updated
- movie_id => foreignkey(movies.id)

> table `rentals_history`

this table is used to track the number of times or rental history of a specific `rentals.id` is rented, returned, or renewed for example

- id(primary key)
- price_paid
- rental_date
- return_date
- renew_date
- rental_status
- rental_id => foreignkey(rentals.id)

**Is there a better way to design these table relationships with the tables `subscriptions_history` and `rentals_history` to track history of another tables `subscriptions` and `rentals`?**

The purpose of the history table is to log every time there is new rental activity like renting, renewed, returned of a movie for example while the rental table is just showing when a specific movie is rented. A movie can be rented multiple times. And each rental can go through different activities before it is returned. Same concept with subscriptions.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest exploring [database normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) and how it drives schema design, and look at how [sakila](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/sakila/en/)/[pagila](https://github.com/devrimgunduz/pagila) implements the movie store concept.

As for the proposed design, get rid of the `subscription` and `rentals` tables and use one table as your transaction log. A simple query can ascertain the status of any subscription or rental. Duplicating the data in a cache table is asking for trouble from race conditions, user errors, etc.

This [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=b72ffed126c965b4f8a95bcf398ebbae) provides an example schema demonstrating this concept.

Comment: so how do i display history of a rental for example...so for a single rental that went through multiple events like `renewed` 2 twice for example before then finally getting `returned`? what i want to do is use one table to track the single rental of a movie and the history table to track the history of the rental...got it?

Comment: this is a very special use-case...where a single row in a table can go through different events over time in another table, which am calling the history table...not many databases or db designs use this particular use-case..so please think this through again

Comment: Looking at your proposed schema, the key (the attributes that uniquely identify one  event) for rentals is {movie_id, rental_date}. The transaction log would have entries for the initial rental, any later renewals, and return.  You can use this key to find all events in the transaction log that occurred for this rental. If it would help, I can put together a fiddle demonstrating the concept.

Comment: sure please...this is a special case that i dont see in public ERD...so really want help from DBA experts willing to help...will appreciate the fiddle...thanks

Comment: I have added a [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=b72ffed126c965b4f8a95bcf398ebbae) to demonstrate the concept.

Comment: thanks a lot for the fiddle...really appreciate it....looked at your fiddle..issue i have is you have the `log` table acting as the rentals table and the rental_history table where it is logging history of changes for a specific rental of a movie...i am trying to separate those...so you are saying not good practice to separate those? i mean what advantage do i get from having them in same table? i want to do it this way for ease of use and easy to understand structure especially when performing sql queries

Comment: also i dont want to use functions..i want to keep things simple...i like simplicity over complexity...willing to lose some tiny performance over simplicity...complexity can ruin things completely in a matter of time

Comment: Yes, duplicating data is poor practice. Inevitably, they stop being duplicates. The functions are purely for example.